# EE update 2.6 to 2.9 : during update cannot select language

Tags: update, language

I am trying to update from 2.6. to 2.9 and when asked to select the language the select menu is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the languages folders from your old to your new system/expressionengine/language folder?

Edit: to make this a more complete answer- The Expression Engine docs on languages http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/languages.html

Comment: I treid to use the language folder from the new zip as well as my old folder.  neither worked.  I ended up reverting back to my last backup.  I will attempt it again and hopefully not get this issue

Comment: Good chance it "just" works. If it doesn't work i'd try smaller steps. Upgrade to 2.7 first, then 2.7.3 etc.